# AWS Robomaker error: (AccessDeniedException) User: arn:aws:iam... is not authorized to perform: robomaker:CreateSimulationJob

Tags: amazon-web-services

[meta.stackexchange.com#141944](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141944/166296) suggests that a question of "AWS + personal usage" like mine can be asked here so hope I'm on the right site.

Following a tutorial of [AWS `Robomaker` (aws.amazon.com)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/robotics/preparing-ros-application-and-simulation-containers-for-aws-robomaker/), in "Create and run robot and simulation applications with containers in AWS RoboMaker" section step 6, running the following command fails with the error (creds replaced).

What am I missing/wrong? I basically created this AWS account afresh, so not so many configuration has been done.

```
$ aws robomaker create-simulation-job --cli-input-json file://create_simulation_job.json

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateSimulationJob operation: User: arn:aws:iam::292945459999:user/fname.lname is not authorized to perform: robomaker:CreateSimulationJob on resource: arn:aws:robomaker:us-east-1:292945459999:simulation-application/robomaker-helloworld-sim-app/1675482941456
```

Content of create_simulation_job.json

(As it's unclear in the tutorial, I made a guess to take ARN of "application" from robomaker-helloworld-sim-app simulation app on Robomaker)

```
    "maxJobDurationInSeconds": 3600,
    "iamRole": "arn:aws:iam::292945459999:role/RoboMaker-HelloWorld-Role",
    "robotApplications": [
        {
            "application": "arn:aws:robomaker:us-east-1:292945459999:simulation-application/robomaker-helloworld-sim-app/1675482941456",
            "applicationVersion": "$LATEST",
            "launchConfig": {
                "environmentVariables": {
                    "ROS_IP": "ROBOMAKER_ROBOT_APP_IP",
                    "ROS_MASTER_URI": "http://ROBOMAKER_ROBOT_APP_IP:11311",
                    "GAZEBO_MASTER_URI": "http://ROBOMAKER_SIM_APP_IP:11345"
                },
                "streamUI": false,
                "command": [
                    "roslaunch", "hello_world_robot", "rotate.launch"
                ]
            },
            "tools": [
                {
                    "streamUI": true,
                    "name": "robot-terminal",
                    "command": "/entrypoint.sh && xfce4-terminal",
                    "streamOutputToCloudWatch": true,
                    "exitBehavior": "RESTART"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "simulationApplications": [
        {
            "application": "arn:aws:robomaker:us-east-1:292945459999:simulation-application/robomaker-helloworld-sim-app/1675482941456",
            "launchConfig": {
                "environmentVariables": {
                  "ROS_IP": "ROBOMAKER_SIM_APP_IP",
                  "ROS_MASTER_URI": "http://ROBOMAKER_ROBOT_APP_IP:11311",
                  "GAZEBO_MASTER_URI": "http://ROBOMAKER_SIM_APP_IP:11345",
                  "TURTLEBOT3_MODEL":"waffle_pi"
                },
                "streamUI": true,
                "command": [
                    "roslaunch", "hello_world_simulation", "empty_world.launch"
                ]
            },
            "tools": [
                {
                    "streamUI": true,
                    "name": "gzclient",
                    "command": "/entrypoint.sh && gzclient",
                    "streamOutputToCloudWatch": true,
                    "exitBehavior": "RESTART"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The IAM user has the following permissions: `AdministratorAccess, AWSDeepRacerRoboMakerAccessPolicy, AWSRoboMaker_FullAccess`

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.27.64 Python/3.8.10 Linux/5.4.0-137-generic botocore/1.29.64
```

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, try https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved myself.

I *think* I forgot to run `aws robomaker create-robot-application` command in the [tutorial (aws.amazon.com)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/robotics/preparing-ros-application-and-simulation-containers-for-aws-robomaker/), as I didn't see robot app on my "Robomaker -> Development -> Robot Applications". So I first (re-)ran:

```
aws robomaker create-robot-application \
--name $robotapp \
--robot-software-suite name=General \
--environment uri=$ecruri/$robotapp:latest
```

Then replacing ARN in `create_simulation_job.json` file with the one the create-robot-application just returned, ran `aws robomaker create-simulation-job` command and the it passed this time, I see a simulation job on "Robomaker -> Simulation run -> Simulation jobs" as expected.

In create_simulation_job.json in the OP, there's one thing clearly wrong: I was passing ARN of "sim app" where that of "robot app" was expected (although the error message didn't make that clear)..

```
    "robotApplications": [
        {
            "application": "arn:aws:robomaker:us-east-1:292945459999:simulation-application/robomaker-helloworld-sim-app/1675482941456",
    :
```